# Hibernate ignore case in property name

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have the following:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I want the following to work:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);

criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("firstName", "john"));

OR     

criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("FIRSTNAME", "john"));

OR 

criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("fiRstName", "john"));
```

Basically, I have a web service that allows filtering of objects on the backend, and we are trying to ignore the case in the name of the properties. I am not sure how to do this. I've searched and looked at the hibernate docs and the Hibernate source, but found nothing. The exception from Hibernate is

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property FIRSTNAME (or fiRstName) of com.abc.Person
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassPropertyTableNumber(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1482)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1457)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.findColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.criterion.SimpleExpression.toSqlString(SimpleExpression.java:68)
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can try generating `MetaModel` class for the entity.

  `criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(Person_.firstName, "john"));`
- Else, in general, you can try fetching declared fields in the class using reflection.

  ```
  Field[] fields = Person.class.getDeclaredFields();      

   for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){

      if(fields[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("FIRSTNAME")){

             criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(fields[i].getName(), "john"));      

             break;
      }
    }
  ```

Comment: I don't think the MetaModel approach will work for our case. The reflection part may be a better solution and we could keep a cache of all fields in memory at start-up to avoid doing the reflection at every call. I hadn't thought about this. I will float it around and see what others think.

The only issue, which shouldn't really be an issue, is fields of the same name with different case in the same entity or entity hierarchy:

    firstName vs firstname.